# Does C++ have an array placeholder similar to Fortran's colon A[2][:]?

Tags: c++, arrays, row, placeholder

Supposing I have an array `A[n][m]`, and I want to read or write to a row/column of `A`.

If I wanted to access the third row of the matrix, how can I reference it like

```
A[3][:]
```

Is this possible in C++ without using a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, C++ has no operator similar to `[:]` in Fortran. Depending on whether you are storing things in row major or column major order, this can be done in similar ways however.

Firstly, arrays aren't really first class citizens in C++. It's much easier to work with either `std::array` (for small `M, N` as these are stack allocated), or `std::vector`.

Let's assume we're using a `std::vector`:

```
template <typename T>
using matrix<T> = std::vector<std::vector<T>>;

matrix<int> m = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}};
```

To get a single row out of this, we can simply use `operator[]`:

```
auto& row = m[0];  // Returns a std::vector<int>& containing {1, 2, 3}
```

Getting columns when it is in row major order is more difficult. If you require more sophisticated sort of operations, using a matrix library (like [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page)) might be a better way to go.

Edit: If you wanted to fill an entire row with zeros, this can be done easily with `std::fill` on the result:

```
//m defined as before
std::fill(std::begin(m[0]), std::end(m[0]), 0);
```

Note that this is still (obviously) linear in the size of the row. This could also easily be wrapped in a function:

```
template <typename T>
void clear_row(matrix<T>& m, std::size_t row, const T& new_value)
{
    std::fill(std::begin(m[row]), std::end(m[row]), new_value);
}
```

If you wanted to replace all the values in a row with a set of different values, you'd use iterators:

```
template <typename T, typename Iterator>
void modify_row(matrix<T>& m, std::size_t row, Iterator new_start)
{
    std::copy(std::begin(m[row]), std::end(m[row]), new_start);
}
```

Comment: I am relatively new to C++. Is there a way to use this to write back into the 2D array? For example, if I wanted to fill an entire row with zeroes?

Comment: Also consider `vector::assign` for both row operations. That's `m[row].assign(m[row].size(), new_value)` to fill and `m[row].assign(new_start, new_end)` to copy from an iterator range of the correct size.

Comment: @SteveJessop Yep. Although using `std::fill` and `std::copy` decouples you from using `std::vector` to using anything that satisfies `operator[]`.

Comment: @Yuushi: `assign()` is part of `Sequence`, isn't it? So it's fairly general. But `std::array` doesn't have it, and is certainly a candidate for the inner structure provided you don't need to efficiently swap rows.

Comment: I see how to use matrix[row].assign to set an entire row. Is there a way to assign the entire "matrix" all at once, not at initialization?

Answer (score 0):

You can only take the last dimension

```
int A[3][5];
int * x = A[2];
int y = x[3];
```

To get `A[?][3]` - you would need a loop

Answer (score 0):

A 2D array is just an array of arrays.

So `int A[10][20]` declares an array of size 10, each of whose elements is an array of size 20, each of  whose elements is an `int`.

The expression `A[3]` has type "array of 20 ints", and you can use it as such. It will decay into an `int *` pointing to the first element of the row (assuming you are thinking of them as rows).

There is no equivalent expression for the columns; you will need a loop for that.

Answer (score 0):

if you define int A[5][10] , then A will have 5 * 10 * sizeof(int) continue space, , 
in this case , A[3][:] would be in 31'th location to 40'th location in this array !!

```
int* p = &(A[30]) ;
```

*(p+0) to *(p+9)  will be A[3][0] to A[3][9] ,  you can directly access each element of A
by the pointer p .

Edit :

typo , it should be :

```
int* p = &(A[3][0]) ;
```

Comment: `int* p = &(A[30]) ;` will not compile.  Either `int* p = A[30];` or `int* p = &(A[30][0]) ;` is required. `int* p = A[30];` is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Not with regular arrays. `std::valarray` supports `std::slice`, which does allow for row access (stride = 1) and column access (stride=row width)